# Underscore, filter out unnecessary objects

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

So I have a huge array of objects that I need to turn into a small one.

it has 50-60 objects and i need to filter into an new array of objects with just 3 of them.

So it looks like

```
myOb = {{"ob1": 1},{"ob2": 1},{"ob3": 1},{"ob4": 1},{"ob5": 1}.....
```

and so on

And I need to turn it into an obj with just ob1, ob2, and ob3 inside of it -
so like

```
 myOb ={{"ob1": 1},{"ob2": 1},{"ob3": 1}}
```

So something like -

```
myOb = _.filter(myOb, function(object){
          return ob1, ob2, ob3 (??)
   });
```

Unsure how to tackle this with underscore(or just plain javascript if underscore is not necessary). Thanks!

Comment: @JamesHill no idea what position they will be in, just know their keys

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just check whether the property exist in the object:

```
myOb = _.filter(myOb, function(obj){
    return 'ob1' in obj || 'ob2' in obj || 'ob3' in obj;
});
```

Alternatively:

```
var keep = {obj1: true, obj2: true, obj3: true};
myOb = _.filter(myOb, function(obj){
    return keep[_.keys(obj)[0]];
});
```

Moaaar underscore.js:

```
var keep = ['obj1', 'obj2', 'obj2']; 
myOb = _.filter(myOb, function(obj){
    return _.some(keep, function(k) { return _.has(obj, k);});
});
```

No underscore.js:

```
var keep = ['obj1', 'obj2', 'obj2']; 
myOb = myOb.filter(function(obj){
    return keep.some(function(k) { return k in obj; });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

From ecma5.1 you can use Array.filter function

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: Does not work in ie8, but gets you out of using a third party library.